# Proof in Shafarevich that local ring is normal

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In Chapter II 5.1 Theorem 1 of *Basic Algebraic Geometry I*, Shafarevich sets about proving that $\mathcal{O}_x$ is integrally closed. He introduces an element $\alpha\in k(X)$ in the form $\alpha=u/v$ where $u,v\in\mathcal{O}_x$. Should this be $u,v\in \mathcal{O}(X)$, the coordinate ring not the local ring? As far as I can judge, the proof then goes through fine.

Comment: Is it a projective variety? There's not a whole lot in $\mathcal{O}(X)$ then. $k(X)$ is still the fraction field of $\mathcal{O}_x$ so nothing about this strikes me as odd.

Comment: @Hoot As it happens I am interested in the case of an irreducible curve. However as $K(X)$ is the field of fractions of $\mathcal{O}(X)$ it seems strange to represent $\alpha$ as the quotient of locally regular rational functions.

Comment: Dear Noel, I think you didn't get @Hoot's excellent point: it is definitely not true in general that $K(X)$ is the field of fractions of $\mathcal O(X)$. This is particularly clear in the case of a projective variety where $\mathcal O(X)=k$, which is already a field so that $\text{Frac}  (\mathcal O(X))=k$, while $K(X)$ is a huge extension of $k$, of transcendence degree $dim(X)$ over $k$.

Comment: @Georges Thank you for the clarification and I see now why Shafarevich has taken the approach he has. As I mentioned I had in mind the case where $X$ is an irreducible algebraic curve where things are I suspect more straightforward. Thank you for sorting things out.